# How to detect if my server is running centos or other from a perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I want to display some text in a script only if the Operating System is Centos .
How can i do that in a perl script ?

Comment: Ask yourself: Where would you look if you were looking yourself? You can most probably replicate this in a perl script.

Comment: Can't you do feature detection instead? That is, what makes CentOS different that you want to display a message?

Comment: Isn't perl but it could be translated to it, http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/21468-machine.html?t=21468#post83185

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your exact question, you can identify CentOS by reading the contents of `/etc/redhat-release`. E.g.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.9 (Final)
```

As other commenters have made clear, it is better to depend on the exact OS features you want, or write code to be portable, rather than limiting it to a particular distribution of Linux.

Comment: Great . But how can i save it as a variable ?
I need something like this :
if ($release=="CentOS")
{
something
}
else
{
something
}

Comment: my $osvar=\`cat /etc/redhat-release\`?

Comment: Unquoted string "cat" may clash with future reserved word at ./test.pl line 2.
Unquoted string "etc" may clash with future reserved word at ./test.pl line 2.
Unquoted string "redhat" may clash with future reserved word at ./test.pl line 2.
Argument "etc" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./test.pl line 2.
Argument "cat" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./test.pl line 2.
Illegal division by zero at ./test.pl line 2.

Comment: @MihaiDomocoş Did you not see/copy the `\``? At any rate I would actually use something like `my $rh_release; {use autodie; open my $fh,'<','/etc/redhat-release'; chomp($rh_release = <$fh>); close $fh}`

Comment: @Brad, do you want autodie there? If the file is missing you probably just want $rh_release to be empty?

Comment: @rjh You mean use something along the lines of `my $rh_release; {open my $fh,'<','/etc/redhat-release' or last; chomp($rh_release = <$fh>); close $fh}` or the more robust `my $rh_release; eval {{open my $fh,'<','/etc/redhat-release' or last; chomp($rh_release = <$fh>); close $fh}};` If you need `$rh_release` to default to `''` instead of `undef`, just start it off with `my $rh_release = '';`

Answer (score 2):

Try `$^O`. It contains the OS that was used to build your version of Perl. Here's what [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) has to say about it.

> The name of the operating system under which this copy of Perl was
>   built, as determined during the configuration process. For examples
>   see PLATFORMS in perlport. The value is identical to $Config{'osname'}
>   . See also Config and the -V command-line switch documented in
>   perlrun. In Windows platforms, $^O is not very helpful: since it is
>   always MSWin32 , it doesn't tell the difference between
>   95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/CE/.NET. Use Win32::GetOSName() or
>   Win32::GetOSVersion() (see Win32 and perlport) to distinguish between
>   the variants. This variable was added in Perl 5.003.

Also see [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#PLATFORMS).

Comment: Good hack, although it relies on the assumption that Linux distributions are built using the same distribution. (Which I'd guess is mostly true, just not 100% reliable.)